# How can I enumerate tasks with MSBuild?

Tags: c++, msbuild

Using msbuild or some other programmatic interface, can I enumerate all the "tasks" in a solution.

For example, if I have a solution "foo.sln" that contains tasks for compiling "a.cpp" and "b.cpp", is there some way to output:

```
>msbuild foo.sln -showtasks

Output:
CL Task: a.cpp ....
CL Task: b.cpp ....
```

Obviously, I'd like to do this without actually executing any of them.